# Using QPluginLoader but throwing error:can't find the dll

Tags: qt

I add resource file to Qt project like this:

[image]

and I use QPluginLoaderin cpp file:

```
QPluginLoader pluginLoader(":/dll/colorbar_plugin.dll");
```

It keeps throwing err:can't find dll file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QPluginLoader expects a file name, not a URL. Additionally the file is expected to be located in the systems library search paths. Try putting your DLL in the same path as the executable and try this:

```
QPluginLoader pluginLoader("colorbar_plugin");
```

If you really must ship your DLL as a ressource, add your resource path to the search paths (including the `qrc:`).

Comment: In fact,I made a stupid mistake,tried to check the err string thrown by Qt before using instance() function.I should instance the dll interface first, then check err string.